# Can't dismiss keyboard between navigation controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm presenting a VC, which is in a navigation controller. If I have the keyboard open and dismiss it, the prior VC still shows the keyboard.

I've tried all suggestions I can find searching, namely:
[How do I dismiss the iOS keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906246/how-do-i-dismiss-the-ios-keyboard)
[No longer able to hide keyboard during viewWillDisappear in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318660/no-longer-able-to-hide-keyboard-during-viewwilldisappear-in-ios7)
[Dismiss Keyboard presented in modal View Controller (Form sheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237932/ipad-ios-7-dismiss-keyboard-presented-in-modal-view-controller-form-sheet)

I've tried adding the "endediting" in viewWillDisappear, also resignFirstResponder on both the search bar AND VC... No luck with any of these..

Comment: Have you tried not calling `resignFirstResponder` in `viewWillDisappear`, but instead in the button / cell callback that will cause it to move to the next screen

Comment: simon is right, make use of resignFirstResponder

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the test case had the issue only happening when the search bar opened the keyboard and then another text field was tapped.. The issue was we have a custom picker but the text field was keeping the keyboard open. I found this and it helped fix my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135784/how-to-disable-keyboard-appearing-when-hitting-on-a-text-field-ios

Comment: Thanks Simon! I had the same problem because I was calling resignFirstResponder in viewWillDisappear, instead I called resignFirstResponder from the callback method for switching VCs and it solved the problem